Finding expectation of X and Y given their conditional expectations
recently I've been studying probability distributions with 2 variables and their expectations, and I came across the following question which I'm unsure about how to go about:
Suppose X and Y are random variables with means $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ respectively; and $E(Y|X=x) = -\frac13x + 10$ and $E(X|Y = y) = -\frac34y+2$. What are the values of $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$?
I'm uncertain whether the variables are discrete or continuous, but I'm making the assumption that it's continuous for both variables. I've tried thinking about the concept of iterated expectation where:
$
E[X] = \sum E[X|Y=y_i]P_y(y_i) = E[E[X|Y]]
$
but I don't have a clue how to make use of it as I don't have the PDF for Y or X, therefore I can't deduce the the marginal PDFs either. Is there another theorem or law I'm missing  that can be used to around this?

Hint: $E[Y\mid X]$ is a random variable that is a function of $X$ that can be taken to be $-\frac 13 X+10$. Similarly for $E[X \mid Y]$. Two applications of the law of iterated expectation will give you two simultaneous linear equations for $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$. Solve these and you are done.

Thanks! I just realized I had to break down the expectations to reduce it to a simultaneous equation.
